# Java - Using a Reentrant lock with Multi-Threading

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I'm making a program with multi-threading, and I want to use a lock. The problem is the program runs on a thread, and I want to have a Thread that grabs the lock, to pause the first Thread, then be able unlock it when a method is called from a third Thread. I tried a bunch of different things, but none of them worked. How should I do this?

EDIT:

Rewrote the question

Comment: An object doesn't lock, a thread does.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The lock `lock.lock()` makes the thread grab the lock, then the next thread to try to grab the lock has to wait until the lock get released with `lock.unlock()`

Comment: And which _thread_ executes `lock.lock()`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis control. look at the code

Comment: **No.** Assuming you're referring to `control.lock();`, you're invoking the `lock` method from a `ControlThread` **object**, but that's not the **_thread_** that's executing that code. The **_thread_** executing the code is the one corresponding to the `Thread` object referenced by `program`.

Comment: Please don't downvote without giving feedback. Just downvoting does not help. I have a question. If you can answer it, answer it, don't downvote.

Comment: That's not how things works. Downvotes show that a question shows no research, is unclear, or not useful. That very much applies here. Please read the help center to understand how the site is designed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that is the thread `control`. `control` is an instance of ControlThread.

Comment: And I did do research. Thats why I'm asking the question. If you want to give me feedback, tell me. Otherwise, it doesn't help

Comment: You're confusing `Thread` objects and executing threads. Each `Thread` object, once started, spawns a _thread_ which can execute code. The thread that's executing the `lock` method is the one associated (started) by the `Thread` object referenced by `program`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so what should I do?

Comment: Start the thread associated with `control` and have it `lock` the `ReentrantLock`.

Comment: So 
 `control.start();
 control.lock();
 System.out.println(lock);`

Comment: No, Again, if you do that, which **_thread_** calls `control.lock()`?

Comment: Program. So what do I do?

Comment: And notice in my question, I asked what to do. I already know that program is executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want a thread to sleep and wait for the notification from another thread. You should look at [Observer and Observable](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077258) instead of locking.